# How can custom code be executed when @BeforeClass fails

Tags: java, junit

I'm using junit to run some integrations tests with docker.

I have a custom TestRule to copy the logs from the containers when a certain test fails:

```
public static class CopyLogsOnTestFailure implements TestRule {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description) {
        return statement(base, description);
    }

    private Statement statement(final Statement base, Description description) {
        return new Statement() {

            final String pathToFolder = "/tmp/logs";

            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try {
                    base.evaluate();
                } catch (Throwable caughtThrowable) {
                    logger.error("Copyings logs on failure!");
                    copyLogs(pathToFolder);
                    throw caughtThrowable;
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Now, if the tests fails in @BeforeClass the logs are not copied since the TestRule is no good for @BeforeClass or @AfterClass methods.

I tried to make the a similar @ClassRule to test solve it but when the testfails in @BeforeClass, it runs @AfterClass, before running the rule. Obviously, in my case, @AfterClass deletes the containers.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

The general order JUnit will execute code is as follows ([blog post with sample code](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2011/09/25/understaning-junit-method-order-execution/)):

```
@ClassRule
  @BeforeClass
    @Rule
      @Before
        @Test
        method1()
      @After
      @Before
        @Test2
        method2()
      @After
    terminate rule
  @AfterClass`
terminate class rule
```

I've indended the execution so you can see more easily which cleanup code will be executed if an exception is raised on what level.

In you first case on using a simple JUnit `@Rule` annotated rule, the exception took place before the rule was executed at all which explains the execution of the `@AfterClass` code.

In the second case, the `@ClassRule` code was executed first followed by code in `@BeforeClass` which produces the exception. Junit will now try to execute the clean up code of the already executed methods. Here `@AfterClass` is executed first, followed by the `@ClassRule` clean up afterwards.

You may refactor your `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` into a further rule and [chain them together with the other rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/rules#rulechain) but you might notice same behavior though as the outer rule is executed before the inner one and if the inner fails, the cleanup of the inner rule is executed followed by the cleanup of the outer rule. If the outer rule fails the inner rule isn't executed at all.

Basically what you want, if I understood your intention correctly, is create an outer rule for the `@AfterClass` cleanup which is doing its cleanup work like this:

```
public class CleanUpRule implements TestRule {

    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description) {
        try {
            base.evaluate();
        } finally {
            // @AfterClass cleanup code here
        }
    }
}
```

The code of the `@BeforeClass` can be put into an other rule

```
public class InitializationRule implements TestRule {

    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base, final Description description) {
        // @BeforeClass logic here
        base.evaluate();
    }
}
```

And then create a chain rule like this:

```
@ClassRule
public static TestRule chain = RuleChain.outer(new CleanUpRule())
                                        .around(new CopyLogsOnTestFailure())
                                        .around(new InitializationRule());
```

JUnit will first invoke the outer rule (`CleanUpRule`) and just invoke the `base.evaluate()` method which will invoke the next rule `CopyLogsOnTestFailure` which also just propagates the call to the next rule the `InitializationRule`. If this rule fails the exception is, due to a missing exception handler, propagated to the predecessor rule `CopyLosOnTestFailure` where the exception handler kicks in and copies the logs to some other location. As the exception is rethrown the exception is now handled by the first rule `CleanUpRule` which simply executes the finally block and therefore executes the former `@AfterClass` cleanup.